# Needed permission to access /dev/diag

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-permissions, root

I am trying to open the /dev/diag using JNI as `open("/dev/diag", O_RDWR | O_LARGEFILE | O_NONBLOCK);` but returning `errno: 13 Permission denied`.

What should be done to make this work?

When checking the ownership of the /dev/diag using the command `ls -l /dev/diag` it returns `crw-rw-rw- system   qcom_diag 244,   0 2015-01-14 01:47 diag`
and when trying to use the command `id` i get `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=u:r:init:s0`

So I thought the problem is related to ownership?

> Update: Based on @HamidShatu answer

I tried to set the SELinux to permissive with no luck.

I tried the command `su 0 setenforce 0` it returns `OK` while still being `Enforcing` if checking immediately using `getenforce` command.

I even tried to change the prop.build: this file did not exist instead a prop.build.bak did so i copied it modified the SELinux to 0 instead of 1 and pushed it without the .bak extension. Even i checked with external applications that modify the prop.build where the SELinux is set to 0 but when checking with the getenforce command it is still returning Enforcing

here is the extract of the dmesg:

```
[18177.676603]  [0: servicemanager:  743] avc:  received setenforce notice   (enforcing=1)
[18182.768070]  [1: servicemanager:  743] avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=1)
[18183.231867]  [0:           init:    1] avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=1)
[18183.232006]  [0:           init:    1] avc:  received setenforce notice (enforcing=1)
```

I even tried to make the app run as system app by adding to the Manifest: `<application--> android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"`

Hint: I am using apps from play store that can access the /dev/diag successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days trying to figure out the solution I was able to bypass the problem by doing the following:

- Instead of using the C code as a shared library where I was struggling to open the /dev/diag I made it as executable C (.c file should have a main function) using Cmake as follows:

  ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
   file(GLOB SRC_FILES
       src/main/cpp/*.c)
   add_executable(
       mylib.so
       ${SRC_FILES}
   )
  ```
- Create a new command in Java that can execute mylib with root priveleage as:

  ```
  new String[]{"su", "-c", "exec " + context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + "/" + "mylib.so"}
  ```
- Execute the command using a process builder

  ```
  process = new ProcessBuilder(command)
               .start();
  ```

The executable is able to use `open("/dev/diag", O_RDWR | O_LARGEFILE | O_NONBLOCK);` with no error!

The reason for that is even in SU mode the application will downgrade to normal mode while executing the function but executing the library in SU mode will ensure its run in su

Answer (score 1):

To understand/analyze your issue, maybe we can first look into what you have posted here.

> I am trying to open the `/dev/diag` using JNI as `open("/dev/diag", O_RDWR | O_LARGEFILE | O_NONBLOCK);` but returning `errno: 13 Permission denied`.

From my experience, `errno: 13 Permission denied` suggest that your code is doing some **SELinux** violations.

> When checking the ownership of the `/dev/diag` using the command `ls -l /dev/diag` it returns `crw-rw-rw- system   qcom_diag 244,   0 2015-01-14 01:47 diag` and when trying to use the command `id`, I get `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=u:r:init:s0`

This portion clearly suggest that `/dev/diag` directory belongs to **Qualcomm**. According to **Android Treble** re-architecture, there are 3 main partitions belong to:

1. Android system (Google/AOSP)
2. Vendor (Chip maker) &
3. OEM (Device maker)

So, according to your analysis, `/dev/diag` belongs to **Vendor** partition.

> So I thought the problem is related to ownership?

The answer of this question is pretty much: Yes.

> What should be done to make this work?

You need to add **SELinux** permission to make this work.
As `crw-rw-rw- system   qcom_diag 244,   0 2015-01-14 01:47 diag` line suggests, you need to add a **SELinux** permission to access `qcom_diag` from `system` for `diag`.

Here's one thing is that, any kind of `diag` permission is given only in **Debug** build, not in  **User** build. Because giving **SELinux** permission for `diag` in **User** build will raise a security concern. It can leak vital information by printing them in logs.

Comment: @MRDRAG I have requested a few things in the comment of that question. Can you please answer those? also please try to explain you purpose more clearly to make it easy for others to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have updated my question according to your answer. How to add SELinux permission to make this work? @Hamid

Comment: is it needed to allow untrusted apps in the SELinux policy? Or the app domain label is sufficient? how to do it? @HamidShatu